# Cannot read property ... of undefined in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, raphael

I'm trying to convert this simple project I made with raphael.js to use backbone.js, but I keep running into this same error and I'm not sure why.  In functions in my Model, i try to access variables using "this" but I'm still getting this error 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined," with an array for example.  My model looks something like this:

```
GameModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {

            spawnId: '',
            gameloopId: '',
            checkId: '',
            goingUp: false,
            counter: 0,     
            recentscores: [],
            enemies: '',
            speed: -4,
            score: 0,
            health: 100,
            paper: '',
            t: '',
            h: '',
            c: '',
            circle: ''

        },
        initialize: function(){

            this.enemies = [];
            this.paper = new Raphael($('#canvas'), 0, 0);
            this.circle = this.paper.circle(100, 50, 30);
            this.t = this.paper.text(1000, 50, "Score: " + this.score);
            this.h = this.paper.text(50, 50, "Health: " + this.health);
            this.c = this.paper.image("background.png", 0, 0, 2400, 800);
            this.paper.setSize(1200,800);
            this.circle.attr({fill: '#9cf', stroke: '#ddd', 'stroke-width': 5});
            this.t.attr({ "font-size": 20, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });
            this.h.attr({ "font-size": 20, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" });
        },
```

Comment: What do these "functions in your model" look like and how do you call them? Also, that `recentscores` in your `defaults` is a bad idea, the defaults are shallow copied so everyone will end up sharing a reference to the same array.

Comment: @muistooshort, they're just function that attempt to access the variables defined within the model.  I have a for loop in one that has the condition "i<this.enemies.length"

Comment: Sure but how are they called? In general, the value of `this` is determined by how the function is called rather than how or where it is defined. And change your `defaults` object to a `defaults` function which returns the default values.

Comment: @muistooshort, Oh hmm, I didn't consider that.  Most of the functions are called from within other functions.  I have a start function which i call after making an instance of my Model, and start calls update, etc.  Could that be the problem?  I'm not sure how I could even access the variables then.  With getters?

Comment: A minimal demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would probably make the problem pretty clear.

Comment: Backbone's properties are not stored directly onto the model object, so that will definitely cause problems with your default values. For instance `console.log(this.score)` is `undefined`, not `0`. You need to use `this.get('score')` and `this.set('score', 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this:

`this.enemies = [];`

Maybe you should try to use

`this.set("enemies", [])`

and

`this.circle = this.paper.circle(100, 50, 30);`

to

`this.set("circle", this.get("paper").circle(100, 50, 30))`